# Jmockit expectations error

Tags: java, jmockit, expectations

I have unit test case where I am using JMockit with expectations. 
Now when I run the test case alone, the test case passes. But when I run all test cases collectively, I get the:

```
expected exactly 1 time, already invoked...
```

error. I feel that some configuration or states set in jmock by previous test cases has not cleared.

Has anyone experienced something similar?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

It sounds to me as if you have defined the allowed number of invocations of a method on a mocked class. Do you have something resembling:

```
@Mock( invocations = 1 )
{signature for method here}
```

?

If this is the case, you need to tear down the mock instance using the JUnit [`@After`](http://junit.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/junit/After.html) idiom, in which you'll to [`tearDownMocks()`](http://jmockit.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/www/javadoc/mockit/Mockit.html#tearDownMocks()) in order to reset the mock instances used in each test case.